# A branch of $\tanh^{-1}z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, logarithms, branch-cuts, branch-points

$\def\Log{\operatorname{Log}}$
How can I show that

$$\frac{1}{2}\Log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$$

defines a branch of $\tanh^{-1}(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}\backslash((-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty))$? (where $\Log$ is the main branch of the logarithmic function)

Actually I don't really see what I have to show to get that result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\tanh w=z$, then 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{e}^w-\mathrm{e}^{-w}}{\mathrm{e}^w+\mathrm{e}^{-w}}=z,
$$
or
$$
\mathrm{e}^w-\mathrm{e}^{-w}=z(\mathrm{e}^w+\mathrm{e}^{-w}),
$$
or
$$
\mathrm{e}^w(1-z)-\mathrm{e}^{-w}(1+z)=0,
$$
or
$$
\mathrm{e}^{2w}=\frac{1+z}{1-z}.
$$
The function $\,h(z)=\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}\,$ possesses a logarithm in 
$\mathbb C\smallsetminus\big((-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)\big)$, since $(1-z)$ possesses a logarithm $g_1$ in $\mathbb C\smallsetminus[1,\infty)$, while $(1+z)$ possesses a logarithm $g_2$ in $\mathbb C\smallsetminus(-\infty,-1]$. Then
$$
g(z)=g_1(z)-g_2(z),
$$
is a logarithm of $\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}$, and thus
$$
\tanh^{-1} z=w=\frac{1}{2}g(z)=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks! I have corrected it now.